# Delete from BST not deleting node

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is an interview prep question on deleting nodes from a BST.

Something wasn't working as expected is when I tried setting node = node.right on line 31. I found that wasn't working as expected, so I had to manually set node.value, node.right, node.left to node.right.* ...which did work. However, now I'm at the case for deleting a leaf(line 36), I've tried setting node=None didn't work for what I expect the same reasons. I've also tried del node that also isn't working.

Why isn't this working as expected? I've traced the code through the debugger, the node variable has the same memory address as the main tree. Is it some kind of scope issue? I don't understand; thanks for the help.

Copying full code below with small example:

```
class Tree(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.value = x
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
def deleteFromBST(t, queries):
    def find(t, q):
        if not t:
            return None
        if t.value == q:
            return t
        if t.value > q:
            return find(t.left, q)
        else:
            return find(t.right, q)

    def delete(t, q):
        n = find(t, q)
        if n:
            if n.left:
                rp = n
                r = n.left
                while r.right:
                    rp = r
                    r = r.right
                n.value = r.value
                rp.right = None

            elif n.right:
                # n = n.right
                n.value=n.right.value
                n.left=n.right.left
                n.right=n.right.right
            else:
                # n = None
                del n

    for q in queries:
        delete(t, q)
    return t

tree_dic={
    "value": 5,
    "left": {
        "value": 2,
        "left": {
            "value": 1,
            "left": None,
            "right": None
        },
        "right": {
            "value": 3,
            "left": None,
            "right": None
        }
    },
    "right": {
        "value": 6,
        "left": None,
        "right": {
            "value": 8,
            "left": {
                "value": 7,
                "left": None,
                "right": None
            },
            "right": None
        }
    }
}
queries=[4, 5, 6,7]
# t=Tree(tt['value'])
def build_tree(d):
    r=Tree(d['value'])
    if d['left']:
        r.left=build_tree(d['left'])
    if d['right']:
        r.right=build_tree(d['right'])
    return r
t=build_tree(tree_dic)
o=deleteFromBST(t,queries)
print('hi')
```